# AJAX request using jQuery switched to Fetch API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fetch

I was  making an AJAX request using jQuery when a button is clicked and when this button is clicked I will get a workflow duplicated, this was working correctly, meaning it was duplicating the same workflow with a new Id so a new record and was redirecting me to this new record in the end,  and then switched the jQuery to using fetch but now I get a page not found message and can't get a result in the backend using PHP

This was the first version of the code

```
function DuplicateWorkflow() {
    const workflowId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('workflow_id');
    if (workflowId) {
        let exporturlworkflow = 'index.php?module=com_vtiger_workflow&action=Export&export_data=selecteddata&filters=&idstring=' + workflowId;
console.log(exporturlworkflow);
        fetch(exporturlworkflow)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(csvData => {
                let exportcsv = csvData;
                console.log(exportcsv);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'index.php?module=com_vtiger_workflow&action=com_vtiger_workflowAjax&file=ImportWFSave&returnwfurl=1',
                    data: {
                        workflowid: workflowId,
                        exportcsv: exportcsv,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //console.log(response);
                        gotourl(response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(alert_arr.DUPLICATE_WF_ERR);
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(alert_arr.ERROR_FETCH_CSV + error);
            });
    } else {
        alert(alert_arr.WORKFLOW_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

And now using fetch I am doing

```
function DuplicateWorkflow() {
    const workflowId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('workflow_id');
    if (workflowId) {
        let exporturlworkflow = 'index.php?module=com_vtiger_workflow&action=Export&export_data=selecteddata&filters=&idstring=' + workflowId;

        fetch(exporturlworkflow)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(csvData => {
                let exportcsv = csvData;
                console.log(exportcsv);
                fetch('index.php?module=com_vtiger_workflow&action=com_vtiger_workflowAjax&file=ImportWFSave&returnwfurl=1', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    },
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    body: csrfMagicName + '=' + csrfMagicToken + '&workflowid=' + workflowId + '&exportcsv=' + exportcsv
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        //console.log(response);
                        gotourl(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert(alert_arr.DUPLICATE_WF_ERR + error)
                    })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(alert_arr.ERROR_FETCH_CSV + error);
            });
    } else {
        alert(alert_arr.WORKFLOW_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

In the browser I am getting a 200 status, and the http requests in the browser are like the same, using JQuery and fetch but I think that data is not being sent in the backend, I get exportcsv as null  if I do gotourl(response.url) to test it in the end .
In php I am doing this

```
...
elseif (isset($_POST['exportcsv'])) {
    $exportCsv = $_POST['exportcsv'];
    $upload_status = file_put_contents('cache/import/wfimport.csv', $exportCsv);
}
```

so didn't change the php after changing to fetch.
Could you help me understand what could be wrong?
Thanks